# Target 2, 3, 6, 7, 10 and so on inside container

Tags: jquery, css

I can't crack this one. How to hit the items like this:
2, 3, 6, 7, 10 and so on... Is there a jQuery or css trick? i just can't figure this out

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* beautifying */
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px; 
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}


.item {
  content: "";
  width: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may be looking for the `nth-of-type(n)` pseudo-class selector - as in `.item:nth-of-type(3)` - more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type

Comment: "[...] and so on..." What does that mean? 11? 12? 13? 14?

Comment: what is the logic/pattern?

Comment: Is the pattern +1, +3, +1, +3?

Comment: If you look at the example, the pattern is criss-crossing across the 2 columns, so it would continue, 11,14

Comment: Use two patters, 4n + 2 and 4n + 3.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @claytronicon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with two selectors: `.container > div:nth-child(4n+2)` and `.container > div:nth-child(4n+3)`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* beautifying */
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  content: "";
  width: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
}

.container>div:nth-child(4n+2),
.container>div:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep!! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the `nth-of-type(n)` pseudo-class selector -

As in `.item:nth-of-type(3)`

In your case, the patterns mentioned by @nurdyguy should work

See sample CSS below in snippet.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* beautifying */
  background: pink;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  content: "";
  width: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
}


/* Selects a patterned .item element */
.item:nth-of-type(4n+2),
.item:nth-of-type(4n+3){
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to this type of series

```
2 3 
6 7
10 11
14 15
18 19
4n + 2 = 2 6 10
4n + 3 = 3 7  11
```

In css you write the nth-child(4n+2) and nth-child(4n+3)

Comment: The 4n + 2  should yield 2, 6, 10, ...  not 2, 6, 8.

Answer (score -1):

Use your css like below:

```
.container>div:nth-child(2),
.container>div:nth-child(3),
.container>div:nth-child(6),
.container>div:nth-child(7),
.container>div:nth-child(10){
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: There is a pattern here, In this example you'd have to explicity target every one. the answer above using .container > div:nth-child(4n+2) and .container > div:nth-child(4n+3) does the trick

Comment: @claytronicon, my answer addresses exactly what the OP asked, he does not mention that there is a pattern. By the way, what is the pattern? How did you infer it from the OP question?

Comment: Actually the OP mentions "and so on..." after the sequence. I inferred it by looking at the example. If you look at the example, the pattern is criss-crossing across the 2 columns starting with "2", so it would continue, 11,14

Comment: "and so on..." could mean "and any other number that I want to explicitly select"... I can see the pattern, I just don't think we should guess what the OP wants if it is not stated in the question.